# loading images based on visibility

Tags: android, image, memory, adapter

This is my issue: I have a "gallery" with 28 images that scrolls vertically, it is giving me an out of memory error when it loads. to overcome this I am attempting to follow this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html to make a cache of all the images and then use an adapter to determine which images are actually on the screen and only have those loaded when needed. This is part of my xml layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="@drawable/background7">

<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"

        android:showDividers="middle">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/Black"
            android:showDividers="end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-35dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/plane1"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:longClickable="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Boeing 757-200"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-35dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/plane2"
                android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="C-17"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-35dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/plane3"
                android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cessna Citation Sovereign"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Each TableRow is a different image, and it continues to 28 images. My question is what kind of adapter do I need to use in order to determine the images that need to be loaded and the general setup to do this, or if their is something less complex that would accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your current setup it's not the best. You would want to use a listview instead of your current layout:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here's a good tutorial about listviews: [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)